# Problem with eclipse text editor

Tags: eclipse, text-editor

Does anyone ever have problem like this??
[image]

The "Enter" , "Tab" , and "space" character is shown .. and I don't know how to fix it. I have tried to restart the Eclipse, change the Android SDK, and also restart my computer. but nothing seems to work. everything stays like that. It's not a relly big problem, but it feels really annoying to see all those character floating around.

anyone have solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the preferences, go to General > Editors > Text Editors and disable "Show whitespace characters". I'm sure you pressed some kind of keyboard shortcut to enable it in the first place.

Comment: ah yes true! looks like I pressed the "Looks like P button" above LOL. There in the image it shown. thanks thanks :D